# C3P0 with hibernate configuration

Tags: oracle, hibernate, c3p0

I am using

spring  4.0.3.RELEASE

hibernate 4.3.5.Final

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    also spring-orm
```

My persistence has below configurations:

```
    <!-- Important -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="30"  />
```

Added these

My application is running on server which has

```
apache-tomcat-8.0.21
JDK 8 version
Oracle 12c
```

I have added these

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
   <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But server log is

```
    Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1677773d -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
        ... 58 more
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at net.divineit.titas.queryBuilders.QueryBuilder.countAll(QueryBuilder.java:395)
        at net.divineit.titas.services.PayrollItemService.list(PayrollItemService.java:69)
        at net.divineit.titas.controllers.EmployeeBenifitsController.getSchema(EmployeeBenifitsController.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2198.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
current thread from acl at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)2014

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
*** z closing connection        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
        at net.divineit.titas.filter.UrlRoleFilter.doFilter(UrlRoleFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at psiprobe.Tomcat80AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat80AgentValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
14:51:38,332  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
14:51:38,333  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
14:51:38,333 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
current thread from acl
2008
*** z closing connection
14:51:38,333 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
        at net.divineit.titas.queryBuilders.QueryBuilder.countAll(QueryBuilder.java:384)
        at net.divineit.titas.services.PayrollItemService.list(PayrollItemService.java:69)
        at net.divineit.titas.controllers.EmployeeBenifitsController.getSchema(EmployeeBenifitsController.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2198.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
        at net.divineit.titas.filter.UrlRoleFilter.doFilter(UrlRoleFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at psiprobe.Tomcat80AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat80AgentValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
14:51:38,335 DEBUG SQL:109 - select payrollite0_.ID as col_0_0_, payrollite0_.NAME as col_1_0_, payrollite1_.ID as col_2_0_, payrollite0_.AMOUNT as col_3_0_, payrollite0_.CALCULATION_METHOD as col_4_0_, payrollite0_.MAX_VALUE as col_5_0_, payrollite0_.MIN_VALUE as col_6_0_, payrollite0_.PARAMETER as col_7_0_, payrollite0_.IS_TAXABLE as col_8_0_, payrollite0_.CREATED_BY as col_9_0_ from PAYROLL.PAYROLL_ITEMS payrollite0_, PAYROLL.PAYROLL_ITEM_GROUPS payrollite1_ where payrollite0_.PAYROLL_ITEM_GROUP_ID=payrollite1_.ID
Hibernate: select payrollite0_.ID as col_0_0_, payrollite0_.NAME as col_1_0_, payrollite1_.ID as col_2_0_, payrollite0_.AMOUNT as col_3_0_, payrollite0_.CALCULATION_METHOD as col_4_0_, payrollite0_.MAX_VALUE as col_5_0_, payrollite0_.MIN_VALUE as col_6_0_, payrollite0_.PARAMETER as col_7_0_, payrollite0_.IS_TAXABLE as col_8_0_, payrollite0_.CREATED_BY as col_9_0_ from PAYROLL.PAYROLL_ITEMS payrollite0_, PAYROLL.PAYROLL_ITEM_GROUPS payrollite1_ where payrollite0_.PAYROLL_ITEM_GROUP_ID=payrollite1_.ID
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1677773d -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
        ... 58 more
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at net.divineit.titas.queryBuilders.QueryBuilder.countAll(QueryBuilder.java:395)
        at net.divineit.titas.services.PayrollItemService.list(PayrollItemService.java:69)
        at net.divineit.titas.controllers.EmployeeBenifitsController.getSchema(EmployeeBenifitsController.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2198.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
        at net.divineit.titas.filter.UrlRoleFilter.doFilter(UrlRoleFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at psiprobe.Tomcat80AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat80AgentValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

Please help me to find out probable issues.

Thanks you.

Comment: I want to figure out as i am not so familiar with c3p0 but why entity manager is closed? probable reason not getting

Comment: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kflt9gcbsnumkjyyb0|14927a0e]-AdminTaskTimer.  ---- This is i got from thread. Almost more than 10 entries are there

Comment: OK. It looks like I screwed up in my initial comment, EntityManager maps to hibernate Session, not SessionFactory, that's EntityManagerFactory. So EntityManagers should close() all the time. There's not much information in any of the symptoms you've posted. If there's an app hang, that could be a Connection leak. When the app is hung, can you ask the JVM to dump its Thread stack trace and see where things look stuck?

Comment: Have edited my question including closing and transaction related functions

Comment: where do your acquire your EntityManager?

Comment: in general, you'll be able to tell if the issue is a Connection leak if you have your JVM dump stack traces when the app his hung. You'll see lots of client Threads wait()ing in a function called awaitAvailable(...). if it is a Connection leak, c3p0 can [help you debug it](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

Comment: hibernate-c3p0 and only c3p0 which dependency i should use?

Comment: hibernate-c3p0 has c3p0 as a transitive dependency, but the version of hibernate you are using brings in an old version of c3p0. i'd override that with the latest [groupId: com.mchange, artifactId: c3p0, version: 0.9.5.2]. you probably do need the hibernate package too, though.

Comment: should not i use   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency> depency but use only c3p0 dependency?

Comment: my guess is that you still need the hibernate-c3p0 dependency, of the same version as the rest of your hibernate components.

Comment: Your question is marked with spring but in your question is nothing spring related. If you combine Spirng and Hibernate there are easier ways to do what you are doing now. With less code and less error prone. If it isn't spring related then please remove the tag.

Comment: Have edited my question with new peoperties and log text